# react-native is not working on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

I ejected the **react-native expo** project to **react-native cli**. But android emulator is not working in it. Bassicaly it gives following error:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.
```

So. how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `Exported`? Do you mean `expo-eject`?

Comment: yes, i mean expo-eject

Comment: My app working well in ```react-native expo``` . but After ejecting it, its not working on  android emulator. I am trying to solve this problem from last 2 days. I chacked gradle file, sdk version , path variables but it still not working. Please help.

Comment: I guess, your React Native setup has not been done properly, Follow the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Comment: i followed the docs but it still not working?